# How to iterate odd indexes and add them back to original list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to add "..." after every odd index in my list (or after every second word), but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like that:

```
sentence = input().split()
ans = []
for i in range(len(sentence)):
  if i%2:
     ans.append(sentence[i]+'...')
  else:
     ans.append(sentence[i])
print(' '.join(ans))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing something like this.Didn't understand your question at first.

```
blah = input().split()

res = "".join(
    word + "..." if i % 2 == 0 else word 
    for i, word in enumerate(blah)
)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def newList(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
       if i%2 != 0:
           lst[i] = str(lst[i]) + "..."
    return lst

>>> l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> print(newList(l))

output:
['a', 'b...', 'c', 'd...', 'e', 'f...']
```